# ColdFusion's cfquery failing silently

Tags: caching, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a query that retrieves a large amount of data.

```
<cfsetting requesttimeout="9999999" >

<cfquery name="randomething" datasource="ds" timeout="9999999" >
    SELECT
        col1,
        col2
    FROM
        table
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#randomething.recordCount#" /> <!---should be about 5 million rows --->
```

I can successfully retrieve the data with python's cx_Oracle and using `sys.getsizeof` on the python list returns 22621060, so about 21 megabytes.

ColdFusion does not return an error on the page, and I can't find anything in any of the logs. Why is `cfdump` not showing the number of rows?

**Additional Information**

The reason for doing it this way is because I have about 8000 smaller queries to run against the `randomthing` query. In other words when I run those 8000 queries against the database it takes hours for that process to complete. I suspect this is because I am competing with several other database users, and the database is getting bogged down.

The 8000 smaller queries are getting counts of col1 over a period of col2.

```
SELECT 
    count(col1) as count
WHERE 
    col2 < 20121109 
AND 
    col2 > 20121108
```

According to [Adam Cameron's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894061/adam-cameron) [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13308712/322909).

- cflog is suggesting that the query isn't finishing.
- I tried changing the queries timeout <strike>both in the code and</strike> in the CFIDE/administrator, [apparently CF9 no long respects the timeout attribute](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2010/7/14/hidden_gem_in_cf9_admin_querytimeout), regardless of what I tried I couldn't get the query to timeout.

I also started playing around with the `maxrows` attribute to see if I could discern any information that way.

- when maxrows is set to 1300000 everything works fine
- when maxrows is 1400000 or greater I get this error
  [image]
- when maxrows is 2000000 I observe my original problem

**Update**

So this isn't a limit of cfquery. By using `QueryNew` then looping over it to add data and I can get well past the 2 million mark without any problems.

I also created a ThinClient datasource using the information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7015557/322909), I didn't observe any change in behavior.

The messages on the database end are

*SQL*Net message from client*

and

*SQL*Net more data to client*

I just discovered that by using the thin client along with `blockfactor1="100"` I can retrieve more rows (appx. 3000000).

Comment: I've found that most times with large data sets, it isn't the query but cfdump. I'd be willing to wager your paycheck that the data is coming back and the browser is crashing trying to render that many records with cfdump (which is a javascript heavy, inline style heavy, mess).  There is no error because cf didn't error, the browser just can't output a dump that large.  Try a simple <cfoutput>#randomthing.recordCount#</cfoutput> instead and see if you get anything.

Comment: @Travis is dumping the recordCount different from what you've suggested?

Comment: It isn't a dump it is just outputting one of the built in cfquery variables, in this case the output is an integer.  there's a few of them, currentRow, recordCount, columnlist.  if you specify the result attribute there's even more.

Comment: @Travis yes, but would the code I've posted `<cfdump var="#randomething.recordCount#" />` affect the system any differently than what you've suggested, `<cfoutput>#randomthing.recordCount#</cfoutput>`?

Comment: cfdump is a troubleshooting tool, if you're just using it to see how many records are returned you can do it with <cfoutput>.  If it is the cfdump that is taking so long, this will tell you. be sure to comment out your cfdump.

Comment: @Travis, looks like I get to keep my meager paycheck. Anyways cfdump filters the display so that only the first 9999 rows show.

Comment: so you commented out the cfdump tag so it doesn't run? 10k rows in cfdump is still a good load for the browser to render. I've had a browser crash loading a cfcatch dump.

Comment: @Travis, he is dumping `randomething.recordCount`, which will only output one value. If he were dumping the entire recordset, there would definitely be an issue with rendering.

Comment: @Travis, It doesn't matter my cfdump isn't dumping the query it's dumping the recordCount. Second my browser isn't having a problem when I set the `maxrows="500000"`.

Comment: You're right, sorry I missed it. Trying to participate on my phone

Comment: @Travis don't sweat it, I'm happy for the second set of eyes.

Comment: My next stack exchange question will be "how four to do I reed?"

Comment: How long is the query taking to run? Any difference if you add `blockfactor="100"` to the cfquery? When you're dealing with that many records, ColdFusion is probably _not_ the right tool.

Comment: @AlEverett `blockfactor="100"` helps. That coupled with Oracles Thin Client increases the number of rows I can retrieve to 3 million.

Comment: Have/Can you run ColdFusion server monitor while you are running this?  Might show something non-obvious.

Comment: @Barry can you turn this comment into an answer I figured it out and this is eventually what got me on the right path.

Answer (score 2):

Is there anything logged on the DB end of things?

I wonder if the `timeout` is not being respected, and JDBC is "hanging up" on the DB whilst it's working.  That's a wild guess.  What if you set a very low timeout - eg: 5sec - does it error after 5sec, or what?

The browser could be timing out too.  What say you write something to a log before and after the `<cfquery>` block, with `<cflog>`. To see if the query is eventually finishing.

I have to wonder what it is you intend to do with these 22M records once you get them back to CF. Whatever it is, it sounds to me like CF is the wrong place to be doing whatever it is: CF ain't for heavy data processing, it's for making web pages.  If you need to process 22M records, I *suspect* you should be doing it on the database.  That said, I'm second-guessing what you're doing with no info to go on, so I presume there's probably a good reason to be doing it.

Comment: Not 22 million records, 22 megabytes worth of data. That shouldn't really be a problem should it? The reason for doing it this way is because I have about 8000 smaller queries to run against the `randomthing` query. In other words when I run those 8000 queries against the database it takes hours for that process to complete. I suspect this is because several people besides me are hitting the database at once.

Comment: Ah sorry, misread. Phew!  Even still, running 8000 queries on `randomThing` sounds like work for the DB server not the CF server. Is there a specific reason why you're involving CF in this? Did you try that other stuff I mentioned?

Comment: can you post what your smaller update query is? There may be a way to rewrite it using an UPDATE statement

Comment: @AdamCameron, According to your cflog suggestion it appears that the query isn't finishing. I tried changing the queries timeout both in the code and in CFIDE/administrator regardless of what I tried I couldn't get the query to timeout. The 8000 smaller queries are getting counts of col1 over a period of col2. `SELECT count(col1) WHERE col2 < 20121109 AND col2 > 20121108`

Comment: OK, that's interesting. I have to say I've never used the `timeout` attribute of `<cfquery>`, but it suggests there's a bug there. How long does the query take to run via that Python route you mentioned?  or natively in SQL Developer / TOAD / whatever-people-use-on-Oracle-these-days? Are you using the drivers that ship with CF? Maybe try some from Oracle. [...]

Comment: [...] Lastly, given what the secondary queries are doing, can you not push all that processing into the DB, and leave CF out of it?  As a rule of thumb, I tend to leave data processing to the DB, and only involve CF with DB stuff when it comes to getting data out to build a webpage.  I do *not* use CF as a data processing engine. It's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: [and I'd just like to say I am getting well sick of Stack Overflow's stupid and pedantic posting rules: I had to break that comment into two because it was too long for one comment, then I had to wait 15sec before I could post the second half. What stupidity is this, honestly? I'm trying to help someone here!]

Comment: @AdamCameron, It takes 2-3 minutes to run the query and receive the data over the network with python, TOAD runs the query slightly faster than python. I am using the drivers that shipped with CF, that is a good suggestion though (I'll look into using alternative drivers) As far as the data processing goes I have to compete with other database users for database resources. The counts are displayed on the page as a table, a table with 21 elements takes about 4 minutes to render.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping your `cfquery` within `cftry` tags to see if that reports anything?

```
<cfsetting requesttimeout="600" >

<cftry>
    <cfquery name="randomething" datasource="ds" timeout="590" >
        SELECT
            col1,
            col2
        FROM
            table
    </cfquery>

    <cfdump var="#randomething.recordCount#" /> <!--- should be about 5 million rows --->

    <cfcatch type="any">
        <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea, but you could give it a go:

You mention that using `QueryNew` you can successfully add the more-than-two-million records you need.

Also that when your `maxRows` is less than 1,300,000 things work as expected.

So why not first do a query to `count(*)` the total number of records in the table, divide by a million and round up, then `cfloop` over that number executing a query with `maxRows=1000000` and `startRow=((i - 1 * 1000000) + 1)` on each iteration...

`ArrayAppend` each query from within the loop to an array then when it's all done, loop over your array pushing the records into a new Query object. That way you end up with a query at the end containing all the records you were trying to retrieve.

You **might** hit memory issues, and it **will** not perform all that well, but hey - this is Coldfusion, those are par for the course, and sometimes crazy things happen / work.

(You could always append the results of each query to the one you're building up from `QueryNew` as you go rather than pushing each query onto an array, but it'll be easier to debug and see how far you get if it doesn't work if you build an array as you go.)

(Also, using multiple queries within the size that it CF can handle, you may then be able to execute the process you need to by looping over the array and then each query, rather than building up one massive query - would save processing time and memory, but depends on whether you need the full results set in a single Query object or not)

Comment: p.s. please take my poke at CF here with a sense of humour - my dev team has been working with it for about ten years and we've covered the full spectrum of loving and hating (not always in that order) it in that time. The other comments about it not being the right tool for the job are probably right, but sometimes it's the tool you have...

Answer (score 1):

if your date ranges are consistent, i would suggest some aggregate  functions in sql instead of having cf process it. something like:

```
select col1, count(col1), year(col2), month(col2)
from table
group by year(col2), month(col2)
order by year(col2), month(col2)
```

add day() if you need that detail level, too. you can get really creative with date parts.

this should greatly speed up the entire run time, reduce the main query size.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that ColdFusion cannot time out SQL. This has always been an issue since CF6 I believe. So basically what is happening is that the cfquery is taking longer than 9999999 seconds but CF cannot timeout JDBC so it waits until afterwards tries to run cfdump (which internally uses cfoutput) and this is reported as timing out because the request is now considered to have run too long.

As Adam pointed out, whatever you are trying to do is too large for CF to realistically handle and will either need to be chopped up into smaller jobs or entirely handled in the DB.

Comment: You're telling me that my query is taking longer than 115.7 days?

Comment: There are probably some sensible internal maximums that we are unaware of. All I can tell you is what my experience is with over 10 years of using CF.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out the server was running out of memory, apparently `cfquery` takes up quite a bit more memory than a python `list`.

[image: CFMonitor Chart]

It was [Barry's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308456/coldfusions-cfquery-failing-silently#comment18675333_13308456) that got me going in the right direction, I didn't know much about the server monitor up until this point other than the fact that it existed.

As it turns out [I am also not very good at reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308456/coldfusions-cfquery-failing-silently#comment18161336_13308456), the errors that were getting logged in the application.log file were

*GC overhead limit exceeded The specific sequence of files included or processed is: \path\to\index.cfm, line: 10 "*

and

*Java heap space The specific sequence of files included or processed is: \path\to\index.cfm*

I'll end up going with Adams [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13308712/322909) and let the database do the processing. At least now I'll be able to explain why things are slow instead of just saying, "I don't know".