# Connection verification failed for data source?

Tags: 32bit-64bit, coldfusion-11

I am using your trial product InterBase ODBC Driver to connect remote borland interbase  7 database.I have verified the connection using Easysoft Interbase ODBC DSN setup(refer attached DSN_connection.png ) and test show connection successfully,but when i tried to refer same System DSN into coldfusion server 11 data source settings,we received the following error message:

```
Connection verification failed for data source: GarrettDB
java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket]internal error: The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLException: [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket]internal error: The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application
```

**Client System Configuration:** 
Here we install InterBase ODBC Driver and create System DSN.

Operating system: Window 2012 server, standard 64-bit

Coldfusion server 11 - 64-bit

**Interbase server System Configuration:**

Operating system : window 2000 server 32-bit

Borland Interbase database - 7

[image]

I didn't figure out why we are getting this error message,Please suggest if you have any solution.

Thanks

Comment: I rarely use ODBC, but that error generally indicates a conflict with 32 vs 64bit components. Searching the archives for that error message *The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application* turns up a a number of results that explain it in more detail, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015557/coldfusion-9-0-1-standard-64bit-and-oracle-11g-64bit-odbc-connection-results-in

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the OBDC driver version you installed on your computer. You need to create a DSN pointing to the 32 bit version of ODBC or to 64 bit version ODBC, depending on which version of ColdFusion you are using. Here are the paths to search for the ODBC Drivers.

- C:\Windows\SysWOW64  or
- C:\Windows\System32 (Depends on the version).

After that please search for the obbcad32 application file and create a DSN there.

If the configuration is good, you can give a try by setting the datasource in another way. Log into the CFAdmin and go to datasources. Create a datasource by selecting **DB2 Universal Database** driver. Specify the same Server Name that you had given when creating in the ODBC Drivers DSN. Hope this helps you.